# Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier. in C# code when I try to insert record by SQL insert statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a method in my C# code that insert record in SQL table , I am getting this error right when I execute insert query:

"Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier."

This is line I have in my C# code that produce error AgencyId and User are both uniqueidentifier in SQl table.

```
db.AddInParameter(command, Agency, DbType.String, dto.AgencyId);

db.AddInParameter(command, User, DbType.String, dto.User);
```

This is my insert Stored proc:

```
     ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insert_ApplicantLoan]
        @RemRef              varchar(15)    = null
       ,@Agency              varchar(100)   = null /* uniqueidentifier */
       ,@User                varchar(100)   = null /* uniqueidentifier */



AS
BEGIN


    INSERT INTO [dbo].[ApplicantLoan]
           ( 
            [RemRef]
           ,[_Agency]
           ,[_User]
          )
     VALUES
           (  
            @RemRef               
           ,@Agency              
           ,@User)

        Set @Id =  SCOPE_IDENTITY() 



        Select @Id
    End



END
```

Comment: Can you show us the data you're trying to convert?

Comment: Did you look at the related column on the right? It seems to be a pretty common problem.

Comment: If you are dealing with uniqueidentifiers (GUIDs) why not use the appropriate types instead of strings/varchars?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen AgencyID=33 and user=partnerpuser

Comment: But "33" is not a uniqueidentifier. `uniqueidentifier` means GUID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, not sure if I misread something, but it looks like your data type in the DB is supposed to be uniqueidentifier. That means that you'll have to update your SP to accept parameters of that type, instead of varchar, as it is now.

Comment: I change the store proc datatype to uniqueidentifier now I am getting this error:   Error converting data type nvarchar to uniqueidentifier.

Comment: Ah, you'll also have to update your C# code, sorry.
You'll need to change DBType.String to DBType.Guid, and then (if not already the case), convert your AgencyId and User values that you pass in to a Guid (new Guid(your_string) for example)